# How to add a Cesium3DTileset to a scene but disable picking events (allowPicking)

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Using Cesium 1.37.

I'm adding two sets of 3D-Tiles to a scene with this code :

```
viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({url : 'data/3DTiles/example_1'}));
viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Cesium3DTileset({url : 'data/3DTiles/example_2'}));
```

This works as expected, the 3D-Tiles are properly displayed.

Now I implemented the code in the "3D Tiles Feature Picking" Sandcastle example  (/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/3D Tiles Feature Picking.html) enabling feature highlight based on mouse events.
This too works as expected.

My problem : I want to disable picking events for the second 3D-Tiles set.

In the Cesium documentation I see a constructor option "allowPicking". Sadly this only seems to be a property for [Primitive](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Primitive.html) object, not [Cesium3DTileset](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Cesium3DTileset.html).

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

I used two nested 3D tilesets, one of them is visualized with transparency. Also i noticed this problem, but couldn't find any direct solution. I used drillPick function in cesiumjs to get all tileset feature candidates from picked position and then filtered features with requested tileset.

```
var scene = viewer.scene;
if (!scene.pickPositionSupported) {
console.log('This browser does not support pickPosition.');
}

var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);
handler.setInputAction(function (result) {

var pickedObjects = viewer.scene.drillPick(result.position);
if (pickedObjects.length >= 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < pickedObjects.length; j++) {
        //Code below removes picked features from array which are not belongs to tileset1.
        if (pickedObjects[j].tileset !== tileset1) {
            pickedObjects.splice(j, 1);
        } 
    }

    var feature = pickedObjects[0];

    if (feature instanceof Cesium.Cesium3DTileFeature) {
        var propertyNames = feature.getPropertyNames();

        var length = propertyNames.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            var propertyName = propertyNames[i];
            console.log(propertyName + ': ' + feature.getProperty(propertyName));
        }
    }

}

}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);
```